# shellscript - accept input and start running in background

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having the script, which take the 2 input's ( sleep time & which server should take back up).

script working fine. but once we given input script should start running in background. pls help

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " pls enter sleep time:"
read sleeping
echo "pls enter server to take archive"
read server
for i in $(cat /moes/home/ranjith/scripts/list)
do
    path=$i
    output="nohup dsmc arch $path -subdir=yes >/tsm/backuplogs/$(basename $path)_\`date +%d%m%y_%H_%M\`.log &"
    ssh $server $output
    sleep $sleeping
done
```

it struck like this

---

```
[root@iitmtsm04 scripts]# ./archive.in
pls enter sleep time:
12m
pls enter server to take archive
iitmtsm04
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a better idea:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [sleep time] [server]"
    exit 1
fi
sleeping="$1"
server="$2"
for i in $(cat /moes/home/ranjith/scripts/list)
do
    path=$i
    output="nohup dsmc arch $path -subdir=yes >/tsm/backuplogs/$(basename $path)_\`date +%d%m%y_%H_%M\`.log &"
    ssh $server $output
    sleep $sleeping
done
```

And you'd invoke it like this:

```
[root@iitmtsm04 scripts]# ./archive.in 12m iitmtsm04 &
```

The `&` at the end instructs the shell to run the given command in background.

More info on command-line parameters, if you're interested: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html

Answer (score 0):

use `screen` command to achieve you objective.

```
[root@iitmtsm04 scripts]# screen
[root@iitmtsm04 scripts]# ./archive.in
```

Enter the input and then use `ctrl + ad` to detatch screen.

Remember to press `ctrl + ad` without removing you finger from ctrl.